# Unable to return functionValue in an XQUERY

Tags: xquery

If I issue below query, then it returns nothing:

```
let $b := doc("books.xml")//book
let $avg := avg( $b//price )
return $avg
```

But following query returns book node satisfying the condition,

```
let $b := doc("books.xml")//book
let $avg := avg( $b//price )
return $b[price > $avg]
```

How so? And how can I return the function value as intended in the former case.

I also tried `return $avg/text()`, hoping to make it work, but no use.
I am using Saxon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What query processor are you using? Are you sure only books with prize>$avg are returned with your second statement? Btw., `
//book[price>avg(//book/price)]` would do it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without let: `avg(doc("books.xml")//book/price)`. Returns 17.86666666666667 for the [books.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sample file you're probably referring to.

You can do it with your `let`-constructions, too, but the function you want to use is called `avg`, not `average`:

```
let $b := doc("books.xml")//book
let $avg := avg( $b//price )
return $avg
```

Comment: Hi Ranon, yes actually I am using avg function only, I have updated my post. But still its not working. I am using saxon.

Comment: `doc("books.xml")//book` outputs every book? I updated my answer, forgot the document-reference as I've stored books.xml as database in BaseX...

Comment: By the way, both your updated query and also mine run flawlessly in saxon (HE, 9.3) and BaseX.